# 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, join, strip

I have a dataset that contains NameAccount of reddit and messages that they have written with time and subreddit. Like this:
[image]

For my porpuse, I need an array with [name of account , all the messages that he has written] (because body (look at the picture) has only one message, but if we see all the authors there will repetitions).

So I have written this program:

```
test_data = pd.read_csv("addres/test_data.csv", encoding="utf8")
test = test_data[['author', 'body']]
lista = [list(x) for x in test.values] 
test=dict()
for i in range(1107946):
    if lista[i][0] in test:
        test[lista[i][0]].append(lista[i][1])
    else:
        test[lista[i][0]]=[lista[i][1]]
```

And I obtain something that I like.
If I write test["Name"] I obtain all the messages of that person.
For example:

```
test["ZenDragon"]

['At 7680 by 4320 with 64x AA, right?',  'Wrong subreddit for this kind of post, but /r/frugal and /r/lifeprotips might be interested.',  'This is something GravityBox can do. (a module for XPosed Framework)',etc]
```

Now I want to join all these lines.
For example: ["message1","message2","message3",etc..] -> ["message 1 message 2 etc..."]
I have tried to write this thing:

```
for i in test.keys():
    X.append(" ".join(line.strip() for line in test[i]))
```

But I have this error:
'float' object has no attribute 'strip'

But i don't have float object?

Comment: If you're getting that error, `line` *must* be a float at some point. Double check your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously there exists a key `i` in your `test` dictionary, whose associated value is a list of elements, at least one of which is not a string, but a float.

You can wrap your code in a try-catch to help and narrow down the cause of your problem:

```
for i in test.keys():
    try:
        for line in test[i]:
            line.strip()
    except:
        print(i)
        print(line)
```